# Modal not loading using javascript in php(CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I want to open model on successful submission of form but although form is submitting modal is not popped up.

```
public function insert($data) {
    // Inserting into your table
    // Calling model
    $done = $this->db->insert('sign_up', $data);

    if($done) {
        echo "<script>$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')</script>";
        echo '<div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you for pre-registering!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Thanks for getting in touch!</p>                     
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
    }
}
```

I am trying to open the model in controller using

```
   $data = array(
            'first_name' => $fname,
            'last_name' => $lname,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $password
        );
        $this->load->model('modal');
        $this->modal->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

CONTROLLER

```
public function insert() {
    $signup_email = $this->input->post('signup_email');
    $signup_password = $this->input->post('signup_password');
    // Checking if everything is there
    if ($fname && $signup_email && $signup_password) {
        $data = array(
              'email' => $signup_email,
              'password' => $signup_password
        );
        if($this->modal->insert($data)) {
             echo "SOME DATA TO BE DISPLAYED IN MODAL";
        }
     }
}
```

VIEW

```
<body>

<div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you for pre-registering!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Thanks for getting in touch!</p>                     
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
     var signup_email = $('#signUp').val();
     var signup_password = $('#signUpPassword').val() ;                  
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo site_url('form/insert'); ?>",
                    data: { signup_email: signup_email, signup_password: signup_password },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data) {
                            $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
                        }
                    }, error: function() {
                        alert("ERROR!");
                    }
                });

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code; this will work

```
public function insert($data) {
    // Inserting into your table
    // Calling model
    $done = $this->db->insert('sign_up', $data);

    // You can do something else here
    if($done) {
?>
        <script>$(document).ready(function(){$('#thankyouModal').modal('show')});</script>
        <div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you for pre-registering!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Thanks for getting in touch!</p>                     
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code of modal in a view file so that we can easily call the modal with javascript in the view file.
And you need to set a variable in flash data so that you can check the condition that the form has been succesfully inserted or not.
Here is the code , I hope it helps you:

Controller file :

```
    public function insert($data) {
    // Inserting into your table
    // Calling model
    $done = $this->db->insert('sign_up', $data);
    // You can do something else here
    if($done) {
      //You can set the message and variable name as per your need.
      $this->session->set_flashdata('inserted','Yes');
      //Redirect to the desired view file
      redirect("controller/anotherfunction_where_view_file_is_loaded");
    }
```

View File:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Thank you for pre-registering!</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Thanks for getting in touch!</p>                     
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php if((isset($this->session->flashdata('inserted'))) && $this->session->flashdata('inserted') != "") { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
    });

</script>

<?php } ?>
```