# Bootstrap modal using redirect() in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I open Bootstrap modal using redirect() in CodeIgniter?
OR
How can I execute a particular div with certain id in views from models?

I am trying to open Bootstrap modal on sucessful submission of form in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this answer for [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692125/modal-not-loading-using-javascript-in-phpcodeigniter/44692570#44692570):

Step 1) Put the HTML of Modal in a view file(which is to be shown after processing has been done from controller).

step 2) Put some flash data from the controller so that you can meet the condition that to show the popup or not.

Step 3) on the view check flash session data has been set or not.
I have already provided the code for controller and view file.

**EDIT**
If you want to redirect to the same page then you have to do all the processing with the help of ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "url/to/your/controller/function",
    success: function(response){
        if(response == "Success"){
            $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
        }else{
            alert("Something just went wrong, Please try again later...");
        }
    },
    error: function(){ 
        alert("Something just went wrong, Please try again later...");
    }
});
```

Comment: How to perform Step 2

Comment: i am giving a new answer for step 2

Answer (score 1):

```
Pass the value for success variable from controller
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if( $success == TRUE ){
?>
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
<?php 
}
?>
</script>

<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the flash data in the following manner

```
   public function insert($data) {
        // Inserting into your table
        // Calling model
        $done = $this->db->insert('sign_up', $data);
        // You can do something else here
        if($done) {
          //You can set the message and variable name as per your need.
          $this->session->set_flashdata('inserted','Yes');
          //Redirect to the desired view file
          redirect("controller/anotherfunction_where_view_file_is_loaded");
        }
```

Note the line "$this->session->set_flashdata('inserted','Yes');"

In this line you can set the flash data in which first parameter will be key and second parameter will be its value,so if you print session variables you will have a key value pair created with the same name.
And please note that the data will be deleted once you refresh the page.

Comment: But where can I place the modal id or do something related to modal

Comment: I am not very much familiar with sessions

Comment: You can put the modal id (or show/call the modal) in the view file. please read my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692125/modal-not-loading-using-javascript-in-phpcodeigniter/44692570#44692570)